# Reply to Outlook mail from Excel

Tags: excel, outlook, reply, vba

I am trying to "replytoall" with a given format in the Body.

I use the following code to search for and display the mails.

```
Sub Test()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Namespace
Dim Fldr As MAPIFolder
Dim olMail As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
i = 1

For Each olMail In Fldr.Items
If InStr(olMail.Subject, "Application for Privilege Leave - Leave ID - Dev-PL-45252-4") <> 0 Then
olMail.Display

i = i + 1
End If
Next olMail
End Sub
```

I need to Replyall with the same subject and a prescribed body and signature.

It is similar to when we open up a mail in Outlook and click on the Reply to All button.

I want it triggered from Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using Early Binding, Change

```
Dim olMail As Variant
```

to

```
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
```

And then you will be able to access all the properties of the `olMail` item. One of which is `.ReplyAll`

**ScreenShot**

[image]

```
If InStr(olMail.Subject, "Blah Blah") <> 0 Then
    olMail.Display
    olMail.ReplyAll

    DoEvents

    '
    '~~> Rest of the code
    '

    i = i + 1
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a *ReplyAll* method which returns a mail object. [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa220145(v=office.11).aspx).
So if you are iterating through some mails, then this should work:

```
For Each oMail in Fldr.Items
    If InStr(olMail.Subject, "mysubject") <> 0 Then
        With oMail.ReplyAll
            .Subject  = oMail.Subject '~~> this is optional
            .Body = "your Body"
            '~~> all other stuff you need your mail to have
            .Display '~~> change to .Send if it is already ok
        End With
    End If
Next
```

Not tested but should be close.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
olMail.ReplyAll
olMail.ReplyAll.body = bodyMail & vbLF & .body
```

Comment: This will never work - the message returned by ReplyAll is never used.