# Compile Error "User-Defined Type Not Defined"

Tags: excel, vba

I have below ReplyAll mail code, during running this code I am facing the following error:

> Compile Error- User-Defined Type Not Defined

I have Pasted below Code & Try to Run this one But getting Compile Error as described above.

```
Sub Test()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Namespace
Dim Fldr As MAPIFolder
Dim olMail As Variant
Dim i As Integer

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
i = 1

For Each olMail In Fldr.Items
If InStr(olMail.Subject, "Application for Privilege Leave - Leave ID - Dev-PL-45252-4") <> 0 Then
olMail.Display

i = i + 1
End If
Next olMail
End Sub
```

[reply-to-outlook-mail-from-excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238635/reply-to-outlook-mail-from-excel)
I expect that this Macro Run without any Error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25238635/reply-to-outlook-mail-from-excel

Comment: You need to set a reference (Tools - References in the VB editor) to the Outlook object library.

Comment: Post code as text....

Comment: I am facing Compile Error-"User-Defined Type Not Defined" when direct running this Macro.

Comment: I am New in the Macro, So how can I set the Reference..

Comment: Can you share any alternate Macro Code for this One to Reply all to same Outlook Conversation through Excel.

Comment: Sandeep, edit your post first. You **have** to add the code as text in this post, not by adding a link or image.

Comment: @SANDEEPJAIN see [Check or add an object library reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/how-to/check-or-add-an-object-library-reference) for how to add a reference. • Also you need to include **your** code that **you** used within your question. A link to a similar code or others peoples code is not enough.

Comment: Unable to add the Code, as per your system there are some Format Issue

Comment: use ``` on the top and bottom of your code

Comment: @SANDEEPJAIN If this was able to help you, please upvote so that the thread can be closed

Answer (score 0):

Follow below steps:

1. Goto the Microsoft Visual Basic Editor where you have your code
2. Click Tools Menu -> References
3. In the window that opens, find Microsoft Outlook 14.0 Object Library (Version can differ on your system depending on what office version you have)
4. Select it and click OK
5. Now run your code.

[image]